# Angular multi-slot transclusion as attribute, not element

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular's [multi-slot transclusion](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude#multi-slot-transclusion) passing an object to transclude such as `transclude: { title: 'custom-title' }`.

To transclude into this, I have to write:

```
<custom-title>...</custom-title>
```

but I want to write it like this for code consistency:

```
<div custom-title>...</div>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create common decorator for directives with multiSlot tranclusion and convert template via template function from

```
<div slot="smth"></div>
```

to

```
<smth><div slot="smth"></div></smth>
```